# Adaptar Datatable jquery a la página

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo la siguiente **Datatable** pero cuando la muestro se muestra de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado con `style="overflow-x:auto;"` como puedo hacer para que se adapte a la pantalla y no que quede como corrido, muchas gracias

```
    <div id="tabla" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" style="overflow-x:auto;">

    <div>

    <table id="tablaSuscriptores" class="table table-striped dt-responsive nowrap" >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Numero Lote</th>
            <th>Orden de Compra</th>
            <th>Fecha de Embarque</th>
            <th>Via</th>
            <th>Destino</th>
            <th>Sales Order</th>
            <th>Customer PO</th>
            <th>Customer Ref</th>
            <th>Cantidad Ordenada</th>
            <th>Cajas</th>
            <th>Bolsas por Caja</th>
            <th>Peso</th>
            <th>Rechazado</th>
            <th>Maximo Bolsas</th>
            <th>Orden Trabajo</th>
            <th>Numero Parte</th>
            <th>Fecha de Inicio</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>               
    </tbody>
    </table>

<button class="btn btn-warning pull-right" style="margin:20px;">Imprimir Suscriptores</button></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usa estas lineas de css

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#tabla, #tablaSuscriptores {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```